# Android App with Gluon/JavaFXPorts using IntelliJ - Android set up incomplete

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gluon, javafxports, gluon-mobile

I've just created a simple app on IntelliJ and and was wondering, why there was so much red coloring in my `AndroidManifest.xml` editor.

I Noticed, that the module set up seems a bit off. Since I'm not an expert yet on IntelliJ, I'd rather ask, before breaking the Gradle or something else.

So in short: How do I set up the project, so that I have full Android support, the support library and the log view integrated.

Thanks in advance.

---

***#edit*** To show my example, here's the `build.gradle` file. Maybe this helps. Also I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.5.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.4-3'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.8'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

plugins {
    id "com.github.ben-manes.versions" version "0.15.0"
}

dependencyUpdates.resolutionStrategy = {
    componentSelection { rules ->
        rules.all { ComponentSelection selection ->
            boolean rejected = ['alpha', 'alpha-preview', 'beta', 'rc', 'cr', 'm'].any { qualifier ->
                selection.candidate.version ==~ /(?i).*[.-]${qualifier}[.\d-]*/
            }
            if (rejected) {
                selection.reject('Release candidate')
            }
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

mainClassName = 'ch.cnlab.monitoring.cross.Main'
// preloaderClassName = 'ch.cnlab.monitoring.cross.Preloader'

dependencies {

    // local Maven dependency
    compile 'ch.cnlab.swag:fx-commons-core:1.0.0'
    compile 'ch.cnlab.swag:fx-commons-afterburner:1.0.0'

    // Gluon Charm
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.3.7'


    // compileNoRetrolambda removed, due to invoke dynamic calls within the newer API version
    compile 'com.airhacks:afterburner.mfx:1.6.3'

    // UI related
    compile 'org.controlsfx:controlsfx:8.40.13'
    compile 'de.jensd:fontawesomefx-commons:8.15'
    compile 'de.jensd:fontawesomefx-fontawesome:4.7.0-5'
    compile 'de.jensd:fontawesomefx-materialdesignfont:1.7.22-4'
    compile 'de.jensd:fontawesomefx-materialicons:2.2.0-5'
    compile 'de.jensd:fontawesomefx-controls:8.15'

    // JSON
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.0'
    // other
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
    // compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.5.0'

    // access to FXActivity
    compile 'org.javafxports:jfxdvk:8.60.9'
    androidRuntime 'org.javafxports:jfxdvk:8.60.9'

    // Kotlin
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:$kotlin_version"
}

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.6.0'
        // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your project context menu instead
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage', 'barcode-scan', 'orientation', 'settings', 'browser', 'device',
                'local-notifications', 'push-notifications', 'runtime-args', 'share'
    }
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        // compileSdkVersion = 22
        // minSdkVersion = 19
        // targetSdkVersion = 22
        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize '2g'
        }
        packagingOptions {
            pickFirst 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            pickFirst 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            pickFirst 'license/LICENSE.txt'
        }
        signingConfig {
            storeFile file('signing/android/my-release-key.keystore')
            File propsFile = file('signing/android/keystore.properties');
            if (propsFile.exists()) {
                Properties props = new Properties();
                props.load(new FileInputStream(propsFile))
                storePassword props.getProperty('RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD')
                keyAlias props.getProperty('RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS')
                keyPassword props.getProperty('RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD')
            }
        }
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'de.jensd.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'javax.xml.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*',
                'com.airhacks.**.*',
                'okio.**.*',
                'okhttp3.**.*',
                'com.fasterxml.**.*',
                'ch.cnlab.**.*'
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I see some red in `xmlns:android URL not registered`,  `android:xlargeScreens not allowed here` and such. Is this what you refer to?. Can't you deploy to an Android device? Can you try opening the Go Native [sample](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/tree/master/go-native)? It has android code, and I don't see any issue, the Android API is available.

Comment: Hi José. Yes, that's the issue I'm referring to. Sorry, that I wasn't clear enough about it! I checked out the samples and opened the `go-native` and faced the exact same problem. The only difference here was, that IntelliJ decided to add the `SBT Shell` view to the bottom, but not the one for Android. On opening the class `AndroidLogService` I was presented with something like _SDK not registered_, uppon selecting it, the Android SDK, API level 22, was set as the projects SDK. But the `AndroidManifest.xml`still remains partially red.

Comment: Oh and yes: I'm able to install the mentioned app (from the question) on Android. But I'm simply not able to debug it from the IDE and missing _some_ content assist.

Comment: I've updated the question and included the Gradle build file. Maybe this somehow helps to find an answer to the question.